# build database for a huge web portal

Tags: java, php, mysql, database

If I want to build a movie website similar to IMDB.
I can have the website up and running.
from the day I launch I can maintain the data upto date, 
but my question, in my mind is How can i think of making the old data available say from 1900 to 2010

This is the challenge that I am facing, can any one share the knowledge how to go about this ?
Which Strategy I can follow to make a any website to make it to have old and as well as the on going News

Say the technology I can think to develop this website would be java, mysql, php

How can i think of making the old data available say from 1900 to 2010 *
Means :  I would like to upload the All the movie data which is very old

Comment: Can you give some more info, "how can i think of making the old data available say from 1900 to 2010". This can be done by storing the release date of movie, also you can get news results for that particular movie if date is known.

Comment: What is the question? Are you wondering about database architecture, or actually harvesting and storing the information? I would recommend a large team to harvest and store the information (since you will most likely have to do much of it by hand), but the structure should not be too complicated. Over-simplified you only need about 7 fields: fields for a unique identifier, movie title, movie director, actors, pictures, information, date. Good luck.

Comment: @RageD - Pretty sure you don't need a large team to write a web crawler.

Comment: @Ben no, not at all. I was assuming he would dig unique information, however. No web crawler can find information that is not on the web already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem here.  Just store the data for all movies in the database, and provide a way for the user to:

- qualify his/her searches with a date range, and
- order the results in date order.

> I would like to upload the All the movie data which is very old

And is there any reason that you can't do this?  (Apart from the obvious one of not having the data in the first place ...)

**FOLLOWUP**

It sounds like the problem you are worrying about is one of incomplete or bad data.  There is no simple solution to that.  You probably need to devise a strategy for dealing with it; e.g.

- upload everything, and then do batch validation / cleanup runs on the live database
- as above, but hide records until have passed validation
- validate each record as you attempt to upload, and put those that fail validation on one side.

You also need to be able to:

- identify common validation problems, and perform bulk corrections,
- change (e.g. tighten) the validation rules on the fly and revalidate.

But this is all standard stuff for a large data-oriented application.  (And there were easy solutions, everyone and their granny would be scraping the internet and building databases.  TANSTAAFL. )

Comment: thanks for your response:::Problem Which I may encounter when Uploading the data from csv or excel sheet to database 
is the with the Foreign Key Mapping.

Comment: @harigm - If you already have the data, figure out what you want your database to look like and build the structure. Then it should be pretty simple to write a script that processes the mess of data you have, and adds it to the normalized DB.

Comment: @Ben ... for some definitions of "pretty simple".